# Деплой из idea на удаленный Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

У меня есть приложение на spring, в процессе сборки получаю war-файл.
Если загрузить руками на удаленный сервер - все ок.
Если запустить на локальном томкат - все ок.

Пытаюсь настроить деплой на удаленной машине, но после деплоя все ресты недоступны, 404 not found.

Можете подсказать шаги и что должно быть чтобы деплой проходил ?

Мои настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз вы используете maven, у него есть tomcat plugin, который сам умеет деплоить. Там у меня указан url: `http(s)://host:port/manager/text`

Comment: @Maxim пробовал такой вариант - не взлетело.
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://myServer:29808/myApp</url>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: myApp это параметр тега `path`. А `url` должен вести к manager, который должен быть доступен по ссылке (кажется в конфигах томката я что-то правил, по дефолту он недоступен).

Comment: @Maxim похоже очень близко к истине, сейчас буду пробовать. В логах нашел это 2-Oct-2018 15:33:32.659 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-135] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [admin]

Comment: при этом я пытаюсь зайти (в settings.xml) под совсем другим пользователем.